# Ability to Reuse input_producer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow training, I am using a `slice_input_producer` to load data. I would like to run over one epoch of my dataset, perform some calculations in Python and then repeat. I have set up the producer like this:

```
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], shuffle=False, num_epochs=1)
```

and then I would like to run:

```
# Ideally this is all wrapped in a for loop:
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        ... = sess.run(f(input_queue))
finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
```

If I don't call `sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())` in each loops after the first get no data. If I do call that, then I get an exception like:

```
INFO in coordinator: Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.AbortedError'>, FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/fraction_of_32_full' is closed.
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.AbortedError: FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/fraction_of_32_full' is closed.
         [[Node: input_producer/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/fraction_of_32_full_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueMany[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32], _class=["loc:@input_producer/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/fraction_of_32_full"], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/fraction_of_32_full, input_producer/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/limit_epochs/_18)]]
```

presumably because the underlying `FIFOQueue` is closed. Is there some way to either reset the queue or remove it from the graph?

This seems related: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2514

An alternative to re-using might just be to remove the queue_runner from the graph: [Remove queue_runner from Tensorflow Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412981/remove-queue-runner-from-tensorflow-graph).

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust `num_epochs` to the number of epoch that you have in your code:

from the Docs:

> num_epochs: An integer (optional). If specified, slice_input_producer produces each slice num_epochs times before generating an OutOfRange error. If not specified, slice_input_producer can cycle through the slices an unlimited number of times.

```
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], shuffle=False, num_epochs=epochs)

    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    try:
        for e in xrange(epochs):   
            while not coord.should_stop():
                ... = sess.run(f(input_queue))
    finally:
        # When done, ask the threads to stop.
        coord.request_stop()

    # Wait for threads to finish.
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: This does not do what I want. I would like to run python code at the end of each epoch and I don't think your solution will notify me that the epoch has  ended.

Comment: you can always pass a callback to the function. Maybe rephrasing the question and posting a semi-working code will help me understand the case.

Comment: I want to run over one epoch of my data, run some python code and then run over another epoch of my data.

Comment: @AlexRothberg did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in a for loop already?

```
for looping_criterion in range(whenever):
  for input in range(one_epoch):
    y = sess.run(f(input_queue))
    .... maybe do other stuff

  # end of one epoch
  do_some_other_function()
#Code now loops back until it reaches whenever
```

Otherwise I'm not really sure I understand the problem you're having could you update your question to expand on it?

Comment: What is the `one_epoch` in this case?

Comment: however much of your data corresponds to one epoch.  Or if your data is batched one_epoch = dataset_size / batch_size

Comment: One epoch is a full pass over the entire data. The data is ideally batched. Unless the data size is exactly a multiple of the batch size, then the last batch will have data spanning two epochs.

Comment: Ah I see your issue now.  Is it a big concern if the slice input producer wraps around and fills in the last batch with previously seen data?  Otherwise I think there is another one of the readers than won't crash if it gets to the end (this assumes the rest of your program can accept different batch sizes).

Comment: It is some of a concern since I want to run on a fixed validation set. What is the other reader that does that? I would love to know. Yes, the rest of the graph (already) deals with with variable batch sizes, though I suppose there might be some perf hit to this.

Comment: The tf.train.batch has allow_smaller_final_batch=False param.  There's also the option of using your own tf.PaddingFIFOQueue.  How is your data currently stored? Would it be too much of a hassle to convert it to a TFRecord and then use the Record reader?